# Fluid simulation visibility of domain

Tags: fluid-simulation, visibility

I am trying to run the fluid simulation in an animation project. Say, the start of simulatin is frame 40, end of simulation is frame 60. But the total animation goes to frame 200. The domain and inflow object should not be visible outside the 40-60 range. If I play with the visibilities, it does not bake. How do I solve this.
Thanks.

Comment: "If I play with the visibilities, it does not bake"? First bake your simulation, then play with the visibilities.

Answer (score 1):

Set start and end keyframe in domain to 40 and 60.

[image]

Uncheck render visibility of inflow

[image]

Set keyframes to render visibility of domain like this:

[image]

39: off

40: on

60: on

61: off

Bake fluid.

result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm also new here and also still new to blender but an idea that came to my mind immediately is to have two scenes or better ".blend files".
One with the fluid simulation and one without.
Render the frames 0 - 40 and 60 - 200 from the one scene with no fluid, and the remaining frames from the scene with the fluid.

After that, just stitch the resulting frames together as you please.

Comment: Thanks everybody. After writing the question, I found another solution which worked: he reduces the scale of domain to 0,0,0 and then at the start of simulation makes it 1,1,1 after which back to zeros.